# How to send data from raspberry pi 3 to my cordova app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, raspberry-pi, data-transfer

First of all, I'm not a very experienced coder but I'm learning and practicing! Currently, I'm trying to develop a *hybrid app with cordova* which is a framework for creating web apps which are able to be installed on ios or android like a native app.

So, I have a private project at home. I want to create an app in order to read the temperature of my bluetooth heater thermostat (comet blue). Thanks to a great tutorial I've found online, I managed to get a connection between my *raspberry pi 3* and the bluetooth heater thermostat with `gatttool`. Now i can read the temperature which is great, but of course I want to display the number on my iphone, in my app to be precise.
How would you implement this? How can I send data from my raspberry to my phone? Preferably over wi-fi? If anyone is aware of a good tutorial for this issue, i would be very grateful.

Thanks!
Em

Comment: The answer probably depends on what type of phone you use - Android, iOS? Will you only use your app where there is wifi - or does your phone provide a wifi hotspot? You could continually transmit the temperature with a simple `bash` script on your RaspberryPi which sits in a loop reading the temperature with `gattool ` and sending it to your phone's IP address using `netcat` over UDP. Presumably you know how to open a socket and read on your device?

Comment: I use iOS and unfortunately, i don't know how to open a socket on my iPhone yet. Thanks for your help! I'll look into netcat right away ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use plain and simple `netcat` to send temperature readings over UDP. Save the following on the Raspberry Pi in a file called `$HOME/transmit`. It runs forever reading the temperature every second with `gattool` and then transmitting it over UDP to your phone:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change these to suit your local setup
PHONE_IP=192.168.0.8
PHONE_PORT=5005

while :; do
   # Read value from thermometer with "gattool" - modify as appropriate
   reading=$(gattool -b BC:6A:29:AE:CC:23 --char-read -a 0x25)
   echo "DEBUG: Read with gattool: $reading"

   # Send to phone with netcat
   nc -w0 -u $PHONE_IP $PHONE_PORT <<< "$reading"

   # Wait a second so we don't flood network
   sleep 1
done
```

Then you can make the script executable with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/transmit
```

And you can run it with:

```
$HOME/transmit
```

Then on your phone, you need to read from the corresponding UDP port. I don't know what your environment is like, but you could do that with `netcat` by saving this on your phone as `$HOME/recv`:

```
#!/bin/bash

PORT=5005

while :; do
   received=$(/usr/bin/nc -w 0 -u -l $PORT)
   echo $received
done
```

Or, if your phone runs Python, this will do the same:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import socket

UDP_IP   = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_PORT = 5005

# Create UDP socket and bind to any/all interfaces
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

# Display all messages received
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print("Received:",data)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you could do this.

On the Raspberry Pi you can write script that uses gatttool to read the temperature and writes the value to a file like /tmp/temperature. Runs this script cron to run this every x minutes to update the value.

Create a 2nd program that's a web server to serve this data over http. You can use any language to do this. Here's how I'd do it with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

```
// serve_temp.js
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  fs.readFile('/tmp/temperature', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end(data);
  });
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

To test it out, write some test data to /tmp/temperature file.

```
echo 70 > /tmp/temperature
```

Run the program

```
node serve_temp.js
```

On your phone open Safari and go to http://raspberrypi.local:3000. You should see "70". (You might need to use the ip address instead of the name. Something like http://192.168.1.123:3000.) Your Cordova app can make this same http call to get data.

You could combine the two programs into one. With Node.js you could use the [noble](https://github.com/noble/noble) library to use Bluetooth and get the temperature from the thermostat.

Another option is to write a Cordova app that talks directly to the thermostat using Bluetooth. You can do this using [cordova-plugin-ble-central](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central).